# cannot find identifier: __mul128

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error (VS2010 sp1) :
**Error 25  error C3861: '_mul128': identifier not found**
Code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <intrin.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __int64* high = nullptr;
    _mul128(2LL,4LL,high);
    return 0;
}
```

Could it be that this fnc can be called only on 64 bit architecture?

Comment: the MSDN example contains: `#pragma intrinsic(_mul128)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_mul128` is only supported on 64-bit architectures. You can see this on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82cxdw50%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
Architecture: IPF, x64
```

Comment: that's what I've just thought. Is there any other way to do multiplication of 64 bit ints on 32 bit architecture?

Comment: @There If you don't need the high 64 bits of the result, you can just multiply two `__int64` variables normally.

Comment: but then I have no way to check if overflow occured.

Comment: @There Then you would need to split the 64-bit numbers into 32-bit numbers and multiply them separately - see the bottom of [this page](http://www.fefe.de/intof.html). For signed numbers it will get a little more complicated. Or you can just use a big-integer library like GMP.

Answer (score 3):

Add `#pragma intrinsic(_mul128)` after the includes.

Comment: I've did what you've said and I'm still getting the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've even set option in VS to use intrinsic fnc and still can't compile it.